# Send select result to web service

Tags: python, python-requests, pyodbc

I have a SQL server database for which i am able to connect and query with pyodbc.
My select statement pulls a container (working for a forwarding company) which I want to pass to a URL using an API to get its data from the port. 
My question is how do I store my select result as a variable and pass it to the URL?

My current code is:

```
cursor.execute ('''SELECT container from container_table ''')   
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:    
    print(row.container)    
    head = {"X-Session-Token":'xxxxxxxxx'}

    ash = ('https://pilot.ports.co.il/WebAPI/api/ContainerStatus/ContainerNumber=**row.container**')         
    getash = requests.get(ash, headers=head)

    print(getash.status_code)
    print(getash.json())
```

Comment: What does this have to do with pyodbc? You literally just want string concatentation or string formatting. I must say that I'm surprised that `row.container` is valid

Comment: @roganjosh - https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#access-values-by-name

Comment: @GordThompson neat, thanks. I assumed pyodbc was more low-level than that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you can use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) with python 3.6 and above:

```
cursor.execute ('''SELECT container from container_table ''')

rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:

    print(row.container)

    head = {"X-Session-Token":'xxxxxxxxx'}

    ash = (f"https://pilot.ports.co.il/WebAPI/api/ContainerStatus/ContainerNumber={row.container}")

    getash = requests.get(ash, headers=head)

    print(getash.status_code)

    print(getash.json())
```